# Cual es el usuario de postgresql por defecto?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

He instalado postgresql voy a acceder a  "sudo vim /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf" y me pide password de postgres y no se cual es ,ayuda

Comment: Si estás editando ese archivo con el usuario postgres, no es necesario el sudo, ya postgres es dueño de ese archivo

Comment: `sudo su postgres` te deja en bash como ese usuario, que es el dueño de todo lo que hay bajo `/etc/postgresql`